# implementing autocomplete textbox in MVC4 through Json

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I want to implement Autocomplete functionality in a textbox. Below is a method which gets a string which is typed in by the user. After selection of unique data, I want to save the ID & Value as well in the database, but I don't know how to handle this code which only returns Value as JSON.

```
public ActionResult BrokerSearch(string broker) {
    //Get BrokerName from database

    var drpList = HelperClass.GetBrokerDropDownValues("brokerCompanyName");
    //var dlist = drpList.ToList().Find(x => x.DropDownListValue.Contains(broker));
    //List<String> arr = drpList.Select(c =>  c.DropDownListValue.ToString()).ToList();
    List < String > arr = drpList.Select(c = > new {
        c.DropDownListValue, c.DropDownListId
    }.ToString()).ToList();

    return Json(arr.Where(t = > t.StartsWith(broker)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

My Javascript is below:

```
  $("#brokerCompanyName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + "/Policy/BrokerSearch",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                broker: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null && data != '') {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        };
                    }))

                } else {
                    $('ul[class*=ui-autocomplete]').hide();
                }
            }
        })
    },
    minLength: 1,
    cache: false,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui != null && ui.item != null) {

            $("#brokerCompanyName").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's giving you the trouble?

Comment: I dont know how to extract the ID of selected value

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#brokerCompanyName").autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Policy/BrokerSearch",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Text, value: item.Value };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: while this may answer the question you should at least add some explanation to your answer.